# LibGDX classes not being found

Tags: android, libgdx, dex

My program is crashing with a

```
03-05 02:21:57.127: E/dalvikvm(12583): Could not find class 'com.deerandcatgames.spikeJumper.GUI.OuyaTable$1', referenced from method com.deerandcatgames.spikeJumper.GUI.OuyaTable.<init>
```

Whenever I run it on android, from the desktop project, it runs fine.

I look at the logcat, and I find the following errors:

```
03-05 02:21:56.907: I/SpikeJumper(12583): Showing screen: SplashScreen
03-05 02:21:56.957: D/dalvikvm(12583): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 23K, 5% free 7525K/7920K, paused 37ms, total 37ms
03-05 02:21:57.127: W/dalvikvm(12583): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/deerandcatgames/spikeJumper/GUI/OuyaTable$1; (347)
03-05 02:21:57.127: W/dalvikvm(12583): Link of class 'Lcom/deerandcatgames/spikeJumper/GUI/OuyaTable$1;' failed
03-05 02:21:57.127: E/dalvikvm(12583): Could not find class 'com.deerandcatgames.spikeJumper.GUI.OuyaTable$1', referenced from method com.deerandcatgames.spikeJumper.GUI.OuyaTable.<init>
03-05 02:21:57.127: W/dalvikvm(12583): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 992 (Lcom/deerandcatgames/spikeJumper/GUI/OuyaTable$1;) in Lcom/deerandcatgames/spikeJumper/GUI/OuyaTable;
03-05 02:21:57.127: D/dalvikvm(12583): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0016
03-05 02:21:57.127: I/dalvikvm(12583): Could not find method com.badlogic.gdx.controllers.Controllers.removeListener, referenced from method com.deerandcatgames.spikeJumper.GUI.OuyaTable.dispose
03-05 02:21:57.127: W/dalvikvm(12583): VFY: unable to resolve static method 2760: Lcom/badlogic/gdx/controllers/Controllers;.removeListener (Lcom/badlogic/gdx/controllers/ControllerListener;)V
03-05 02:21:57.127: D/dalvikvm(12583): VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x0007
03-05 02:21:57.127: W/dalvikvm(12583): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/deerandcatgames/spikeJumper/GUI/OuyaTable$1; (347)
03-05 02:21:57.127: W/dalvikvm(12583): Link of class 'Lcom/deerandcatgames/spikeJumper/GUI/OuyaTable$1;' failed
03-05 02:21:57.137: D/dalvikvm(12583): DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x26b5 at 0x18 in Lcom/deerandcatgames/spikeJumper/GUI/OuyaTable;.<init>
03-05 02:21:57.187: D/dalvikvm(12583): GC_CONCURRENT freed 399K, 8% free 7578K/8236K, paused 3ms+5ms, total 29ms
03-05 02:21:57.257: I/SpikeJumper(12583): Setting up custom table
03-05 02:21:57.257: W/dalvikvm(12583): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x418a3930)
03-05 02:21:57.257: E/AndroidRuntime(12583): FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 19356
03-05 02:21:57.257: E/AndroidRuntime(12583): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.deerandcatgames.spikeJumper.GUI.OuyaTable$1
03-05 02:21:57.257: E/AndroidRuntime(12583):    at com.deerandcatgames.spikeJumper.GUI.OuyaTable.<init>(OuyaTable.java:72)
03-05 02:21:57.257: E/AndroidRuntime(12583):    at com.deerandcatgames.spikeJumper.screens.AbstractScreen.getTable(AbstractScreen.java:84)
03-05 02:21:57.257: E/AndroidRuntime(12583):    at com.deerandcatgames.spikeJumper.screens.AbstractScreen.resize(AbstractScreen.java:52)
03-05 02:21:57.257: E/AndroidRuntime(12583):    at com.deerandcatgames.spikeJumper.screens.SplashScreen.resize(SplashScreen.java:49)
03-05 02:21:57.257: E/AndroidRuntime(12583):    at com.badlogic.gdx.Game.setScreen(Game.java:63)
03-05 02:21:57.257: E/AndroidRuntime(12583):    at com.deerandcatgames.spikeJumper.SpikeJumper.setScreen(SpikeJumper.java:61)
03-05 02:21:57.257: E/AndroidRuntime(12583):    at com.deerandcatgames.spikeJumper.SpikeJumper.resize(SpikeJumper.java:79)
03-05 02:21:57.257: E/AndroidRuntime(12583):    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGraphics.onSurfaceChanged(AndroidGraphics.java:334)
03-05 02:21:57.257: E/AndroidRuntime(12583):    at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1505)
03-05 02:21:57.257: E/AndroidRuntime(12583):    at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1240)
```

The OuyaTable is

```
public class OuyaTable extends Table {
....
}
```

I have tried everything I can think of, and it still will not run on the android. Has anyone seen this before, and/or knows how to fix it?

Comment: Perhaps `Table` (which `OuyaTable` extends from) is not available in Android?

Comment: it is, this is why I had libgdx in the tags, as Table is a LibGDX class, `com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Table`

Comment: Did you put your libraries (`*.jar`s) in `/libs` folder?

Comment: Yes I did. `/libs` contains `gdx-backend-android.jar` and `gdx-controllers.jar` they are also added through eclipse, and checked in the export dialog. I double checked with a fresh working new project, it does not have `gdx.jar` added through the android project's `\libs` and instead the base project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, trying again but paying more attention to the error messages... I see:

```
Could not find method com.badlogic.gdx.controllers.Controllers.removeListener, referenced from method com.deerandcatgames.spikeJumper.GUI.OuyaTable.dispose
```

As one of the reasons the link failed.  I think you must be using the libgdx "controllers" extension ... you need to add the `gdx-controllers-android.jar`.  See the "Integration Into Your Project" section of the badlogic blog: http://www.badlogicgames.com/wordpress/?p=2724

Comment: That is also added in. I forgot to mention that in the thing sorry.

Comment: Okay marking this as the answer, because it was SO close to the actual problem, I HAD included `gdx-controllers-android.jar` ... I just forgot to include `gdx-controllers.jar` Stupid mistake I know.

Answer (score 0):

The `gdx.jar` (which contains the platform-independent Libgdx classes) probably didn't get packaged into your Android .APK.  (Versus the Android-specific Libgdx classes which are packaged in `gdx-backend-android.jar` and did seem to make it into your .APK.)

You need to make sure your Android project is exporting the `gdx.jar`.  Right-click on your Android project in *Project Explorer*, select *Properties*, select *Java Build Path*, and select the *Order and Export* tab.  Make sure `gdx.jar` and `gdx-backend-android.jar` are both "checked" (along with your common project).

Comment: It is checked, that was one of the first things I checked, but it still seems to fail.

Comment: Which version of the Android Dev Tools are you using?  (There were some weird build problems with ADT17).  Which Libgdx version?

Comment: LibGDX nightly, and v21 of the ADT. It fails though even with latest stable, 0.9.8.

Answer (score -1):

java=caca, adt=caca, eclipse=.....
I 've had this problem, solved changing the main project (star-assault in the tutorial) from java 1.7 to java 1.6 after getting mad for couple of hours...